# How to sort an array ("10a", "23a", "1a", "2a") using VBScript

Tags: sorting, vbscript

How to sort below array

```
Dim testarray = new Array("10a", "23a", "2c", "2a")
```

using VBScript to give output like `"2a", "2c","10a", "23a"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only solution i found is to split the numeric part and then compare the numeric part first and then the character part.

```
Function sort(iparrary)
For i = 0 to ubound(iparrary)
        For j= i+1 to ubound(iparrary)
            num1 = getnumber(iparrary(i))
            num2 = getnumber(iparrary(j))

            if (num1 <> "" and num2 <> "") then
                if cint(num1) > cint(num2) then
                    temp  = iparrary(i)
                    iparrary(i) = iparrary(j)
                    iparrary(j) = temp
                End if  
            End if

            if num1 = num2 or num1="" or num2 = "" then
                if(iparrary(i) > iparrary(j)) then
                    temp  = iparrary(i)
                    iparrary(i) = iparrary(j)
                    iparrary(j) = temp  
                End if
            End if      
        Next    
    Next
End Function

Function getnumber(strnumber)

    dim intnum
    intnum  = ""

    For num = 1 to len(strnumber)
        chardata = mid(strnumber,num,1)
        if isnumeric(chardata) then
            intnum= intnum & chardata
        else
            getnumber = intnum
            Exit function
        End if      
    Next
    getnumber = intnum
End Function
```

works exactly how i wanted.

Comment: This is basically what I suggested, only with a custom comparator. Which I was unable to devise, since you elected to not disclose the intended order of the items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) instead of an array:

```
testarrray = Array("10a", "23a", "2c", "2a")

Set testlist = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For i=0 To UBound(testarray)
    testlist.Add testarray(i)
Next

For Each e In testlist
    WScript.Echo e
Next

testarray.Sort

For Each e In testlist
    WScript.Echo e
Next
```

Otherwise you'll have to implement a [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) yourself. VBScript doesn't have that functionality built into it.

For simple cases like your example bubblesort is probably the easiest to implement:

```
Function Bubblesort(ByVal arr)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        For j = i + 1 to UBound(arr)
            If arr(i) > arr(j) Then
                tmp    = arr(i)
                arr(i) = arr(j)
                arr(j) = tmp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Bubblesort = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry this works only for numeric or character sort. I need to sort like 1,1a,1b, 2a, 2c...have an easy solution in. C#. Not sure  if any better way of implementing with vbscript.

Comment: I'd doubt there is.

Comment: you will find many solutions with c# in stackoverflow itself. :)

Comment: I doubt there is a better way of implementing this with VBScript.